# iOS app upload video to facebook with a remote url without downloading the video

Tags: ios, facebook, url, video, upload

It seems like in order to upload video to facebook, I will need to download the video data from a remote hosted file. Is that a correct assumption?

Is it possible to just provide the video url and have Facebook handle the video upload in the background?

My app lets the user to upload their video to a server for some video processing and eventually got a url for the processed video. Then I want to let them to upload that processed video to their Facebook news feed. It will be inefficient if the app needs to perform upload 2 times.

```
NSString * filePath = @"http://mywebsite.com/my_video.mp4";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           videoData, @"video.mp4",
                           @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                           @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                           @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                           nil];
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                 andParams:params
             andHttpMethod:@"POST"
               andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Have you got any resolution on this? i am also kinda in same situation.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?